# Manipulating an existing document using node jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, coffeescript

I'm using [node-jquery](https://github.com/coolaj86/node-jquery), and I'd like to use it to modify an existing document - which is all the way from the doctype to closing html tag.

But I'm finding node jquery a little off -

```
$ = require 'jquery'
$('body').append "<div class='testing'>Hello World</div>"
console.log $("body").html()
```

Returns:

```
<div class="testing">Hello World</div>
```

Note the lack of a body tag, which in normal jquery would have been required. It's like there's a blank document - which I'm fine with, except appending a full document makes makes jquery crash.

How can $("body").append() work in a document that has no body? Is anyone else using node-jquery? Is it considered stable? How can I use it to manipulate an existing document?

Comment: if you're using chrome (and maybe this applies to other browsers) it's because chrome substitutes for incomplete code adding in a body if there isn't one.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm not using a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log $('body').html()` will output the innerHTML of your body tag, which propably only is the newly created div. Try `console.log $('body').parent().html()`

Comment: Thanks - console.log $("html").html() was what I went for in the end. It seems node Jquery starts with an partial document by default.